# Python - In-line boolean evaluation without IF statements

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, boolean, apply

I am trying to assess the value of a column of a dataframe to determine the value of another column.  I did this by using an `if` statement and `.apply()` function successfully. I.e.

```
if Col x < 0.3:
    return y
elif Col x > 0.6:
    return z
```

Etc.  The problem is this takes quite a while to run with a lot of data.  Instead I am trying to use the following logic to determine the new column value:

(x<0.3)*y + (x>0.6)*z

So Python evaluates TRUE/FALSE and applies the correct value.  This seems to work much faster, the only thing is Python says: 
"UserWarning: evaluating in Python space because the '*' operator is not supported by numexpr for the bool dtype, use '&' instead
  unsupported[op_str]))"

Is this a problem?  Should I be using "&"?  I feel using "&" would be incorrect when multiplying.

Thank you!

Comment: What dataframe? ``pandas``, ``pyspark``, ...?

Comment: Are you sure that the `if` statements are what's taking time?  If you aren't doing anything else in them, `if` statements should be essentially instantaneous.

Comment: I think the apply()s make it much slower?

Comment: @jbndlr its a PANDAS dataframe.  My boolean process runs in 4 minutes versus the multiple apply() if statement process which takes 30minutes.  I am just concerned about this "UserWarning".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show your actual code that covers this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read so far, the performance gap is issued by the *parser* backend chosen by `pandas`. There's the regular python parser as a backand and, additionally, a pandas parsing backend.
The docs say, that there is no performance gain if using plain old python over pandas here: [Pandas eval Backends](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#pandas-eval-backends)

However, you obviously hit a white spot in the pandas backend; i.e. you formed an expression that cannot be evaluated using pandas. The result is that pandas falls back to the original python parsing backend, as stated in the resulting UserWarning:

> UserWarning: evaluating in Python space because the '*' operator is not supported by numexpr for the bool dtype, use '&' instead
>     unsupported[op_str]))

[(More on this topic)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#technical-minutia-regarding-expression-evaluation)

### Timing evaluations

So, as we now know about different parsing backends, it's time to check a few options provided by `pandas` that are suitable for your desired dataframe operation (complete script below):

```
expr_a = '''(a < 0.3) * 1 + (a > 0.6) * 3 + (a >= 0.3) * (a <= 0.6) * 2'''
```

1. Evaluate the expression as a string using the `pandas` backend
2. Evaluate the **same** string using the `python` backend
3. Evaluate the expression string with external variable reference using `pandas`
4. Solve the problem using `df.apply()`
5. Solve the problem using `df.applymap()`
6. Direct submission of the expression (no string evaluation)

The results on my machine for a dataframe with 10,000,000 random float values in one column are:

```
(1) Eval (pd)    0.240498406269
(2) Eval (py)    0.197919774926
(3) Eval @ (pd)  0.200814546686
(4) Apply        3.242620778595
(5) ApplyMap     6.542354086152
(6) Direct       0.140075372736
```

The major points explaining the performance differences are most likely the following:

- Using a python function (as in `apply()` and `applymap()`) is (**of course!**) much slower than using functionality completely implemented in C
- String evaluation is expensive (see (6) vs (2))
- The overhead (1) has over (2) is probably the backend choice and fallback to also using the `python` backend, because `pandas` does not evaluate `bool * int`.

Nothing new, eh?

### How to proceed

We basically just proved what our gut feeling was telling us before (namely: pandas chooses the right backend for a task).

As a consequence, I think it is **totally okay** to ignore the UserWarning, as long as you know the underlying *hows and whys*.

Thus: Keep going and have `pandas` use the fastest of all implementations, which is, as usual, the C functions.

### The Test Script

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def conditional_column(val):
    if val < 0.3:
        return 1
    elif val > 0.6:
        return 3
    return 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nr = 10000000
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': [random.random() for _ in range(nr)]
    })

    print(nr, 'rows')

    expr_a = '''(a < 0.3) * 1 + (a > 0.6) * 3 + (a >= 0.3) * (a <= 0.6) * 2'''
    expr_b = '''(@df.a < 0.3) * 1 + (@df.a > 0.6) * 3 + (@df.a >= 0.3) * (@df.a <= 0.6) * 2'''
    fmt = '{:16s} {:.12f}'

    # Evaluate the string expression using pandas parser
    t0 = timer()
    b = df.eval(expr_a, parser='pandas')
    print(fmt.format('(1) Eval (pd)', timer() - t0))

    # Evaluate the string expression using python parser
    t0 = timer()
    c = df.eval(expr_a, parser='python')
    print(fmt.format('(2) Eval (py)', timer() - t0))

    # Evaluate the string expression using pandas parser with external variable access (@)
    t0 = timer()
    d = df.eval(expr_b, parser='pandas')
    print(fmt.format('(3) Eval @ (pd)', timer() - t0))

    # Use apply to map the if/else function to each row of the df
    t0 = timer()
    d = df['a'].apply(conditional_column)
    print(fmt.format('(4) Apply', timer() - t0))

    # Use element-wise apply (WARNING: requires a dataframe and walks ALL cols AND rows)
    t0 = timer()
    e = df.applymap(conditional_column)
    print(fmt.format('(5) ApplyMap', timer() - t0))

    # Directly access the pandas series objects returned by boolean expressions on columns
    t0 = timer()
    f = (df['a'] < 0.3) * 1 + (df['a'] > 0.6) * 3 + (df['a'] >= 0.3) * (df['a'] <= 0.6) * 2
    print(fmt.format('(6) Direct', timer() - t0))
```

Comment: THank you for the detailed response!  It validates what I thought - Apply is much sloer than in line boolean!

I managed to find a way to result the user warning.  I used the function ".astype('int')" which converted all the TRUE and FALSE statements to 1s and 0s - hence no error message!

Cheers